# Rails3 ActiveRecord and custom SQL JOINS with default_scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wordpress, activerecord, scope

I need to map a non-existing table to ActiveRecord (in my case: the Wordpress Database Schema), which consists of a custom SQL statement as described below. I want to be able to use find(), first(), all() among other statements. Is there a way to accomplish this without actually overwriting all the finder methods? (i am currently redefining those methods, to accomplish similar results, but would love to know if there is a more ActiveRecord/Rails way to do so)

currently i am doing for example

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
   self.table_name="wp_terms"
   def self.all
     Category.find_by_sql("select distinct(wp_terms.term_id),wp_terms.name,wp_term_taxonomy.description,wp_term_taxonomy.parent,wp_term_taxonomy.count from wp_terms inner join wp_term_relationships ON wp_term_relationships.object_id = wp_terms.term_id INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy ON wp_term_taxonomy.term_id = wp_terms.term_id where taxonomy = 'category';")
   end
end
```

thanks for any pointers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [default scope](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Default/ClassMethods/default_scope):

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
   self.table_name="wp_terms"

   # Individual scopes for readability - the names could be improved.
   scope :select_scope, select("DISTINCT(wp_terms.term_id), wp_terms.name, wp_term_taxonomy.description, wp_term_taxonomy.parent, wp_term_taxonomy.count")
   scope :join_scope, joins("INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships ON wp_term_relationships.object_id = wp_terms.term_id INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy ON wp_term_taxonomy.term_id = wp_terms.term_id")
   scope :where_scope, where("taxonomy = 'category'")

   default_scope select_scope.join_scope.where_scope
end
```

Then you should be able to call any finder method on `Category` without having to implement it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Would you consider creating a view-backed model as outlined in [Enterprise Rails](http://books.google.ie/books?id=thTju-4duY4C&lpg=PP1&ots=nFmsRSwKu0&dq=enterprise%20rails&pg=PA147&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false)?